# fuzzy query is not work using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I am reading the documentation of elastic search and using the fuzzy query but it won't work

I am following the below documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

postman

GET https://localhost:0000/myindex/_search

I have a 3 records

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 4,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "default",
                "_id": "ioSZw4UBBGNKkg-oBT13",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Rahul_Patil",
                    "contents": {
                        "topic": "Elasticsearch with postgresql configuration",
                        "details": "test index"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "default",
                "_id": "jYRCxIUBBGNKkg-ojj36",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Rahul_Patilt_test_Index",
                    "contents": {
                        "topic": "Elasticsearch with postgresql configuration 2",
                        "details": "test index 3"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "default",
                "_id": "j4RexIUBBGNKkg-owj3w",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Rahul_Patil_test_Index_updates_new",
                    "contents": {
                        "topic": "Elasticsearch with postgresql configuration update",
                        "details": "test index update"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "default",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "abc_Index",
                    "contents": {
                        "topic": "abc 2",
                        "details": "abc 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

now I change body->raw

GET https://localhost:0000/myindex/_search

body->raw

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
       "_source.name": {
        "value": "Ra"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the response is ok but I am not able to find whose name starts with Rahul_Patil

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Comment: the fuzzy can edit max 2 positions. you must informe more texto in you term. Rahul_Patim -> Rahul_Patim. Doc Elastic: The elasticsearch fuzzy query type should generally be avoided. Acts much like a term query. Does not analyze the query text first.

Comment: @rabbitbr ```{
  "query": {
       "match":{
    "fuzzy": {
      "value": "Rahul",
      "fuzziness":2
    }
       }
  }
}``` not work when I use fuzziness 2

Comment: @rabbitbr  it is give an error ```"reason": "[match] query does not support [value]",```

Comment: this way works:
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "Rahul_Pati",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}